# how to change point styles in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I want to pass styles for different points when plotting
Something like this

```
curve = self.graphWidget.plot(xs, ys, brushes=['''a list with different styles for points'''])
```

[image: smth like this]

Tell me how this can be implemented, without placing points separately